# Append one table to another table

Tags: sql

I have following situation:

```
Table 1:
A     B  C
2012  4  2
2012  3  1

Table 2:
A     B  C
2013  3  2
2013  3  1
```

My result should look like this:

```
Table X
A     B   C
2012  4   2
2012  3   1
2013  3   2
2013  3   1
```

So I just want to append Table 2 to Table 1. They have the same columns

Comment: look into `union`

Comment: Hint:  `UNION ALL`.  Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *new* table, then use `create table as` or the equivalent in your database:

```
create table x as
    select a, b, c
    from table1
    union all
    select a, b, c
    from table2;
```

If you want to "append" the values onto the first table, use `insert`:

```
insert into table1 (a, b, c)
    select a, b, c
    from table2;
```

Note that tables in SQL represent *unordered* sets.  You have not specified any ordering, so once the rows are in a single table, the original source (and ordering) is not preserved -- unless you include this information in separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

The UNION should allow you to merge the tables

```
SELECT a,b,c from table1
UNION
SELECT a,b,c from table2
```